# Spring4で、特定フィールドのみをselectした結果をエンティティーにキャストする方法

Tags: java, spring

リポジトリクラスで、特定フィールドのみをselectしたメソッドの戻り値を、
Object[]ではなくエンティティーに自動でキャストしてもらう方法はないのでしょうか？

ドキュメントにもそれらしきものがなかったので、ご存じの方がいらっしゃいましたらご教授願います。
http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#core.repository-populators

EntityRepository.java

```
@Repository
public interface Entity extends JpaRepository<Entity, Long> {
    // 実際の戻り値はList<Object[]>になるが、エラーにはならない
    @Query("select e.id, e.data from Entity e where e.name = ?1")
    List<Entity> findByName(String name);
}
```

Entity.java

```
@Entity  
@Table(
    name = "entity"
)
public class Entity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="id", nullable=false)
    private long id;
    @Column(name="name", nullable=false)
    private String name;
    @Column(name="data", nullable=false)
    private String data;

    ... getter setter...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JPAでクエリの結果をエンティティオブジェクトに入れる方法はいくつかありますが、
Spring DataでJPAを使う場合となると、「コンストラクタを作り、クエリ（JPQL）で呼び出す」という方法しかなさそうです（独自実装コードを書かないという前提）。

```
public class Entity {
  public Entity(long id, String data) {
    this.id = id;
    this.data = data;
  }
  // 以下質問にあるコードと同じ
}

@Repository
public interface Repository extends JpaRepository<Entity, Long> {

  @Query("select new package.Entity(e.id, e.data) from Entity e where e.name = ?1")
  List<Entity> findByName(String name);
}
```

英語版stackoverflowにも同様の質問と回答がありました。
jpa - Is there a way to transform objects that spring data repositories return? - Stack Overflow 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22360744/is-there-a-way-to-transform-objects-that-spring-data-repositories-return